# Twillio message send fails with Carrier Network status Status Not Received/Undelivered

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I sent 4 messages to a user over a few hours but only one of the messages was received (the first message).

The 3 that failed are marked as sent, however when I inspect them in the twilio sms logs the delivery step in Carrier Network says “Status Not Received” after 1 hour, then “undelivered” after 5 hours. The user was expecting the messages and has not tried to block messages from us in any way (i.e. texted STOP).

Why would he receive one of the messages and not the rest? also why would this happen?

thankyou in advance for your help!

Comment: It is probably better to [contact Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) supplying them with the example message SIDs you are having this trouble with. They will be able to trace the messages and see what happened.

Comment: Hey man, cheers for posting, I have contacted them also. It seems to be really strange behaviour that google was turning up nothing for. I posted here also incase someone else experiences something similar or has in the past.

Comment: Did you manage to find out what this means? I have the same problem. If you found out what caused the "Status Not Received" error could you post it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to contacting support directly you might have a look at this [troubleshooting guide](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181868-How-can-I-troubleshoot-if-an-SMS-message-sent-from-Twilio-doesn-t-arrive-) here and look for any of the specific error codes listed in [the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#error-values).

The errors message range in specificity answering why this could happen:

- `Queue overflow`
- `Account suspended`
- `Unreachable destination handset`
- `Message blocked`
- `Unknown destination handset`
- `Landline or unreachable carrier`
- `Carrier violation`
- `Unknown error`
- `Missing segment`
- `Message price exceeds max price`